# Swapping every letter with every other letter in a string

Tags: java

I am doing a project and I have come up with some code to swap every letter with every other letter in a string, only the project was to be "efficient as possible".

Example:

```
"rya" = yra, ray, ayr.. etc
```

I understand exactly how the code works. I would just like to make it efficient as possible.

```
public String testSwap(String word) {

char[] charArr = word.toCharArray();
char[] charArr2 = new char[word.length()];
String newString = "";

for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
        int count = 0;

        for(char c: charArr) {
            charArr2[count] = c;
            count++;
        }

        if(charArr2[i] != charArr[j]) {
            charArr2[i] = charArr[j];
            charArr2[j] = charArr[i];

            newString = new String(charArr2);

            if(graph.keySet().contains(newString)) {
                return newString;
            } else {
                newString = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
return newString;
}
```

NOTE: The `if` statement inside is for the current project I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> to swap every letter with every other letter in a string

In other words you need all permutations of a string. Ok not all: no need in null set.

> I would just like to make it efficient as possible.

Just wanted to show you another solution. A crazy one with a recursion:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string

```
public static void permutation(String str) { 
    permutation("", str); 
}

private static void permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) System.out.println(prefix);
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
}
```

Quick solution to get it in one line with commas:

```
public static String permutation(String str) {
        String res = permutation("", str);
        return res.substring(0, res.length()-2);
    }

private static String permutation(String prefix, String str) {
    String res = "";
    int n = str.length();
    if (n == 0) res = res + prefix + ", ";
    else {
         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
             res = res + permutation(prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i+1, n));
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Output:
rya, ray, yra, yar, ary, ayr

Less code, but definitely not the most efficient: calling charAt and substring a lot of time - not a good way.

**In that link there are alot of other examples how to do it.**